# Node pointer in the definition of node itself, how does it work?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Consider this `struct` definition:

```
struct node {
   int age;
   struct node* next;
};
```

1. How is it possible to have `struct node *next` in `struct node {...}` when it is in the definition of `struct node` itself?
2. What would the value of `sizeof(struct node*)` be?
3. With:

   ```
   struct node* to_add = (struct node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   ```

Does `to_add` only have the address of the allocated memory?

Although I have used and implemented data structures in C/C++, however I have some basic doubts. Could you please help me understand the doubts which I have. I tried to search on-line, however the doubts still remains the same.

Comment: Read up on the differences between a *declaration* and a *definition*.

Comment: You are asking 4 different question which makes this too broad.  Can you please narrow it down?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Could you please answer for Question #1. Actually I have doubt in all these questions, else I ask one question usually.

Comment: 1. You can have a pointer to incomplete type because at the point of member declaration, you only need to know the size of a type which is 2. `sizeof(node*) == sizeof(void*)` - same for all pointers. The rest is not that clear.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Can't really answer a "how is this clearly possible thing possible" without knowing where your confusion is.

Comment: @CuriousMind _" I have used and implemented data structure in C/C++"_ Note there's no such language as C/C++ please. They are different programming languages, and have different mechanisms and behaviors, but share some keywords and behaviors though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an MS Painted pictorial description of what such a `node` would look like:

[image]

Each `node` has a value (42, 69, or 613 in this example) and each holds a pointer to the next node, the last node holding a pointer to nothing.

This isn't an infinite recursive structure - a `node` doesn't have a `node` member, it has a `node*` member. And a pointer is just a pointer, another memory address. `sizeof(node*)` is the same as the size of any other pointer (whether 4 or 8 bytes). `sizeof(node)` is more interesting, but dependent on padding and other alignment issues. On a 32-bit machine, it'll probably be 8 bytes. On a 64-bit machine, it'll probably be 16 bytes (with 4 bytes of padding in the middle).

Answer (score 3):

1. Because you only need a declaration of a type to define a pointer to that type.  The start of the `struct` definition declares the type so you're ok to have pointers to that type inside it.
2. `sizeof(struct node*)` returns the size of the pointer
3. `malloc` returns a pointer to heap memory of the type's size but the memory is uninitialized.
4. The size is right but it's uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

A declaration is sufficient to create a pointer. E.g.

```
struct node;
struct node* nodePtr = NULL;
```

The size of a pointer does not depend on the full definition of the object. Hence you can use:

```
struct node;
struct node* nodePtr = NULL;
size_t s = sizeof(nodePtr);
```

Since creation of a pointer does not depend on the full definition of the `struct`, it is possible to use:

```
struct node { // At this point struct node is a declared type.

   int age;

   // Since struct node is a declared type, you can create a pointer
   struct node* next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **It's a pointer.** Pointer definitions are naturally opaque--that is, the only thing that we need to know to be able to have a pointer is that the thing it points to has a constant size (as per all C and C++ non-templated types). Opaque pointers, in fact, are a way of making an encapsulated API in C/C++; it's used for stuff like SDL.
2. **It should normally be the size as any other pointer.** Pointers are usually implemented as simple memory addresses, but memory itself can be a complicated situation depending on the architecture and software it is running on. On x86-64, I believe the size is the same as one word, which is 8 bytes.
3. **Depends on implementation or architecture.** Normally (meaning x86 or x86-64), yes.
4. **Yes.**

One more thing; note that `sizeof(Node)` and `sizeof(age) + sizeof(next)` can be different sizes due to *compiler alignment*. Compilers often try to make memory multiples of word sizes or a different size (e.g. cache size) to make memory access better for architectures that optimize for alignment to word size.

Comment: pointer are generally 4 bytes on 32 bit systems and 8 bytes on 64 bit systems.

Comment: Sort of sneaky to call an 8-byte quantity a word on x64, I see your point but it doesn't match x64's own jargon

Comment: @harold I'm using the more general definition, which can be considered the more "correct" definition that applies to computer architecture in general. `word` is the legacy 16-bit word size where x86 and its derivative were first created. They, again, probably kept their lingo for backwards compatibility.